# Como saber si una letra es Mayuscula

Tags: c#

Tengo una cadena de Texto y las siguientes dos lineas de codigo:

```
string texto = "HolaComoEstas";
string resultado = texto.Toupper......
```

Como pueden notar tengo una cadena de texto, que no tiene espacios entre palabras, lo que intento hacer es identificar la mayuscula y hacer un replace para agregar un espacio entre palabras y asi sucesivamente con la siguiente, de manera que mi resultado quede asi:
"Hola Como Estas"

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Usando expresiones regulares:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string texto = "HolaComoEstas";
string resultado = Regex.Replace(texto, "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim();
```

O bien de forma manual:

```
string texto = "HolaComoEstas";
string resultado = texto;

for (int i = 1; i < resultado.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(resultado[i]))
    {
        resultado = resultado.Insert(i, " ");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Si las cadenas que vas a separar son bastante largas, considera usar `StringBuilder` para mejor desempeño:

```
using System.Text;

string texto = "HolaComoEstas";
StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(texto);

for (int i = 1; i < resultado.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(resultado[i]))
    {
        resultado = resultado.Insert(i, " ");
        i++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```